# Assign a number to Day of Week using Case in Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to assign a number to a Day of Week field in Data Studio. So for Monday I want to return 1, Tuesday 2, Wednesday 3 and so on where Sunday will be 7.

I have written the below case statement which is accepted by Data Studio but when I add the field to a Table or Pivot Table all days return a null value.

This is the Case Statement

[image: Case Statement]

And this is what is returned when adding the **Day Number** field to a pivot table. The 3rd column in the **Day Number** field.

[image]

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM datetime_expression)

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Samuel. This does the trick for sure. Thanks for your help, this is going to save me a ton of time going forward. Cheers